# Xunit CSV streamReader.ReadToEnd returns System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: css, xunit, streamreader

I would like to evaluate a CSV data series with Xunit.
For this I need to read in a string consisting of int, bool, double and others.
With the following code, the transfer basically works for one row.
But since I want to test for predecessor values, I need a whole CSV file for evaluation.
My [Theory] works with InlineData without errors.
But when I read in a CSV file, the CSVDataHandler gives a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException!

I can't find a solution for the error and ask for support.
Thanks a lot!

```css
        [Theory, CSVDataHandler(false, "C:\\MyTestData.txt", Skip = "")]
        public void TestData(int[] newLine, int[] GetInt, bool[] GetBool)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newLine.Length; i++)
            {
                output.WriteLine("newLine {0}", newLine[i]);
                output.WriteLine("GetInt {0}", GetInt[i]);
                output.WriteLine("GetBool {0}", GetBool[i]);
            }
        }
```

```css
    [DataDiscoverer("Xunit.Sdk.DataDiscoverer", "xunit.core")]
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]

    public abstract class DataArribute : Attribute
    {
        public abstract IEnumerable<object> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo);
        public virtual string? Skip { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class CSVDataHandler : DataAttribute
    {
        public CSVDataHandler(bool hasHeaders, string pathCSV)
        {
            this.hasHeaders = hasHeaders;
            this.pathCSV = pathCSV;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            var methodParameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
            var paramterTypes = methodParameters.Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pathCSV))
            {
                if (hasHeaders) { streamReader.ReadLine(); }
                string csvLine = string.Empty;

                // ReadLine ++
                //while ((csvLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                //{
                //    var csvRow = csvLine.Split(',');
                //    yield return ConvertCsv((object[])csvRow, paramterTypes);
                //}

                // ReadToEnd ??
                while ((csvLine = streamReader.ReadToEnd()) != null)
                {
                    if (Environment.NewLine != null)
                    {
                        var csvRow = csvLine.Split(',');
                        yield return ConvertCsv((object[])csvRow, paramterTypes); // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static object[] ConvertCsv(IReadOnlyList<object> cswRow, IReadOnlyList<Type> parameterTypes)
        {
            var convertedObject = new object[parameterTypes.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.Count; i++)
            {
                convertedObject[i] = (parameterTypes[i] == typeof(int)) ? Convert.ToInt32(cswRow[i]) : cswRow[i]; // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                convertedObject[i] = (parameterTypes[i] == typeof(double)) ? Convert.ToDouble(cswRow[i]) : cswRow[i];
                convertedObject[i] = (parameterTypes[i] == typeof(bool)) ? Convert.ToBoolean(cswRow[i]) : cswRow[i];
            }
            return convertedObject;
        }
    }
```

```css
MyTestData.txt 
1,2,true,
2,3,false,
3,10,true,
```

Comment: Probably just a typo here, but in your code you wrote ``public abstract class DataArribute`` instead of ``DataAttribute``-- two r's instead of ttr.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` will return the entire contents of the file in a string, not just one line. When you call `csvLine.Split(',')` you will get an array of 12 elements.

The second call to `streamReader.ReadToEnd()` will not return `null` as your `while` statement appears to expect, but an empty string. See the docu at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend?view=net-7.0

> If the current position is at the end of the stream, returns an empty
> string ("").

With the empty string, the call to call `csvLine.Split(',')` will return an array of length 0, which causes your exception when its first element (index 0) is accessed.

All of this could have been easily discovered by simply starting the test in a debugger.

It looks like you have some other issues here as well.

I don't understand what your `if (Environment.NewLine != null)` is intended to do, the `NewLine` property will never be null but should have one of the values "\r\n" or "\n" so the if will always be taken.

The parameters of your test method are arrays `int[]` and `bool[]`, but you are checking against the types `int`, `double` and `bool` in your `ConvertCsv` method, so the alternative `cswRow[i]` will always be returned. You'll wind up passing strings to your method expecting `int[]` and `bool[]` and will at latest get an error there.

Comment: Hello Christopher,

I have now tried all known variants of the problem solution and still fail.
Neither a splitCounter nor an iteration over the rows to be read lead to a solution of the problem. Partly the variables are not recognized or in the wrong order when debugging .....
ReadToEnd does not seem to be successful in any case?

Is there any other way besides CSVDataHandler to read data from a CSV into Theory?

Comment: Your method ``ConvertCsv`` is returning an array of simple strings instead of an array of arrays of int's and bool's as your test method requires. To proceed step by step, first modify the ``GetData`` to simply construct three arrays ``newline``,  ``GetInt`` and ``GetBool`` directly using c# code, e.g. ``newline = new int[3]; newline[0] = 1; newline[1] = 2``  etc. ,  instead of reading from the file. Then ``yield new object[] {newline , GetInt, GetBool}``. Once you get that working you can start to worry about how to fill these three arrays from your CSV file to be able to yield them.

Answer (score 0):

This method reads a data series from several rows and columns and returns it as an array for testing purposes.
The conversion of the columns can be adjusted according to existing pattern.
Thanks to Christopher!

```css
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
    public class CSVDataHandler : Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute
    {
        public CSVDataHandler(string pathCSV)
        {
            this.pathCSV = pathCSV;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            List<int> newLine = new();
            List<int> GetInt = new();
            List<bool> GetBool = new();
            var reader = new StreamReader(pathCSV);
            string readData = string.Empty;

            while ((readData = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] split = readData.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                newLine.Add(int.Parse(split[0]));
                GetInt.Add(int.Parse(split[1]));
                GetBool.Add(bool.Parse(split[2]));
                // Add more objects ...
            }
            yield return new object[] { newLine.ToArray(), GetInt.ToArray(), GetBool.ToArray() };
        }
    }
```